# VB.net XAML datagrid cell colour change based on value

Tags: vb.net, xaml, colors, datagrid, cell

My XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Datagrid_Binding"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="8517" Width="1244">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="WaterfallDataGrid" CanUserSortColumns="False" ColumnWidth="60" AutoGenerateColumns="False">



            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Load" Binding="{Binding Load}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="PF" Binding="{Binding PF}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Spare" Binding="{Binding Spare}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Load}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="Full Load">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>


        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My VB.net code.

```
Class MainWindow
    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Dim dt3 As New DataTable("Waterfall")

        dt3.Columns.Add("Load")
        dt3.Columns.Add("PF")
        dt3.Columns.Add("Spare")
        'dt3.rows.add(New Object() {"full load", "0.8", "20%"})
        dt3.Rows.Add("full load", "0.8", "20%")
        WaterfallDataGrid.ItemsSource = dt3.DefaultView

    End Sub
End Class
```

What I would like to do is when the cell has the text "full load" it changes its cell colour. I am getting an error at runtime which says "Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource." Very puzzled with this. Some help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you defined the same column twice.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Grid>
            <DataGrid x:Name="WaterfallDataGrid" CanUserSortColumns="False" ColumnWidth="60" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Load" Binding="{Binding Load}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="full load">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="PF" Binding="{Binding PF}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Spare" Binding="{Binding Spare}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Comment: Not sure how this will solve my problem as what I am looking for is for the cell to change colour if the cell contains the wording "full load"...

Comment: This is to avoid the exception.

Comment: Forget about the Loaded event. the problem is the way you defined the columns. The style should be defined under the column definition or in the resources section.

Comment: That's awesome Myriam. Thanks a bunch.